# ¿Por qué el CSS no aplica en esta tabla?

Tags: css

No entiendo por qué el CSS no aplica en esta tabla:

```css
.tabla-cuaresma {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tabla-cuaresma td,
th {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.tabla-cuaresma thead {
  background-color: rgba(130, 50, 162, 0.72);
}

#titulo-cuaresma {
  background-color: rgba(121, 60, 144, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="tabla-cuaresma">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">SEMANA-DÍA</th>

        <th>HOMILÍAS</th>

        <th>LECTURAS</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tr>
      <td></td>

      <td>Miércoles</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-00_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-04-miercoles-ceniza" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Jl</strong> 2, 12-18: <em>Rasgad vuestros corazones, no vuestros vestidos</em><br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 50, 3-4. 5-6ab. 12-13. 14 y 17: <em>Misericordia, Señor, hemos pecado</em><br>
        <strong>2 Cor</strong> 5, 20—6, 2: <em>Reconciliaos con Dios: ahora es tiempo favorable</em><br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Mt-06_01-06-y-16-18" target="_blank"><strong>Mt</strong> 6, 1-6. 16-18</a>: <em>Tu Padre, que ve en lo secreto, te recompensará</em><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>

      <td>Jueves</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-00_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-05-jueves-despues-de-ceniza" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Dt</strong> 30, 15-20: <em>Mira: yo os propongo hoy bendición y maldición</em><br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 1, 1-2. 3. 4 y 6: <em>Dichoso el hombre que ha puesto su confianza en el Señor</em><br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Lc-09_22-25" target="_blank"><strong>Lc</strong> 9, 22-25</a>: <em>El que pierda su vida por mi causa la salvará</em><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>

      <td>Viernes</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-00_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-06-viernes-despues-de-ceniza" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Is</strong> 58, 1-9a: <em>Este es el ayuno que yo quiero</em><br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 50, 3-4. 5-6ab. 18-19: <em>Un corazón quebrantado y humillado, oh Dios, tú no lo desprecias</em><br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Mt-09_14-15" target="_blank"><strong>Mt</strong> 9, 14-15</a>: <em>Cuando les sea arrebatado el esposo, entonces ayunarán</em><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>

      <td>Sábado</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-00_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-07-sabado-despues-de-ceniza" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Is</strong> 58, 9b-14: <em>Cuando ofrezcas al hambriento de lo tuyo, brillará tu luz en las tinieblas</em><br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 85, 1b-2. 3-4. 5-6: <em>Enséñame, Señor, tu camino, para que siga tu verdad</em><br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Lc-05_27-32" target="_blank"><strong>Lc</strong> 5, 27-32</a>: <em>No he venido a llamar a los justos, sino a los pecadores a que se conviertan</em><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="titulo-cuaresma">
      <th colspan="4"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="false">SEMANA I (DOMINGOS)</i></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>I</td>

      <td>Domingo (A)</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias-ciclo-a_semana-01_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-01-domingo" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Gn</strong> 2, 7-9; 3, 1-7<br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 50, 3-4. 5-6ab. 12-13. 14 y 17<br>
        <strong>Rm</strong> 5, 12-19<br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Mt-04_01-11" target="_blank"><strong>Mt</strong> 4, 1-11</a><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>I</td>

      <td>Domingo (B)</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias-ciclo-b_semana-01_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-01-domingo" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Gn</strong> 9, 8-15<br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 24, 4-5a. 6-7cd. 8-9<br>
        <strong>1 Pe</strong> 3, 18-22<br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Mc-01_12-15" target="_blank"><strong>Mc</strong> 1, 12-15</a><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>I</td>

      <td>Domingo (C)</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias-ciclo-c_semana-01_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-01-domingo" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Dt</strong> 26, 4-10: <em>Profesión de fe del pueblo escogido</em><br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 90, 1-2. 10-15: <em>Está conmigo, Señor, en la tribulación</em><br>
        <strong>Rm</strong> 10, 8-13: <em>Profesión de fe del que cree en Jesucristo</em><br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Lc-04_01-13" target="_blank"><strong>Lc</strong> 4, 1-13</a>: <em>El Espíritu lo fue llevando por el desierto, mientras era tentado</em><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="subtitulo-cuaresma">
      <th colspan="4">Ferias Semana I</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>I</td>

      <td>Lunes</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-01_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-02-lunes" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Lv</strong> 19, 1-2. 11-18: <em>Juzga con justicia a tu prójimo</em><br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 18, 8. 9. 10. 15: <em>Tus palabras, Señor, son espíritu y vida</em><br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Mt-25_31-46" target="_blank"><strong>Mt</strong> 25, 31-46</a>: <em>Cada vez que lo hicisteis con uno de estos, mis hermanos más pequeños, conmigo lo hicisteis</em><br></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Aquí funciona, y en una prueba que hice en local también, **pero en mi sitio no funciona** y no entiendo por qué. No pone los colores de fondo al `thead` ni tampoco al elemento con id `#titulo-cuaresma`.

He probado usando `!important`, he limpiado la caché del navegador y nada.

El sitio está alojado en Wordpress, y yo cargo el css correctamente, en el código fuente puedo ver el archivo de estilos cargado y puede ver el código indicado más arriba.

La URL donde se encuentra la tabla [es esta](http://www.deiverbum.org/liturgia/cuaresma/#Calendario_General_de_las_celebraciones_de_Cuaresma).

Comment: @JackNavaRow no se considera una buena práctica trabajar con ID (le hice alguna vez la pregunta a alguien que trabaja directamente con la especificación de CSS).

Comment: @JackNavaRow yo había leído lo mismo que comenta Shaz, hay que evitar los ids si es posible. Es cierto que es más fácil alcanzar los elementos, pero si mal no recuerdo en algunos casos pueden romper la cascada o algo así. El hecho es que si se pueden evitar, es mucho mejor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El estilo que aplicas está siendo "sobreescrito" por unos estilos más generales, en elementos "hijos", en este caso:

```
tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}
```

y posteriormente:

```
th {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

por lo cual sería mejor en efecto aplicar los tuyos al `<th>`

Comment: Por cierto creería que tienes un pequeño error tipográfico en los enlaces: `target="_blank&quot;"`

Comment: Efectivamente, se estaba sobre-escribiendo como sospechaba. Aplicando así se resolvió el problema: `.tabla-cuaresma thead th {
    background-color: rgba(130, 50, 162, 0.72);
}

#titulo-cuaresma th {
    background-color: rgba(130, 50, 162, 0.72);
}` . Gracias por lo del `&quot;` lo había visto y la verdad no entiendo de donde sale. Yo genero los enlaces de forma dinámica por PHP, revisé el código y no hay nada extraño ahí: `$enlace = '<a href="'.URL_DOMINIO.'homilias'.$id_ciclo.$semana.$strTiempo.$dia.'" target=_blank">Homilías</a>';` tengo que investigar eso. Gracias.

Comment: El `&quot;` fue fruto de una validación que hice para probar el código HTML en local, en realidad no existe en la página. Es mi validator el que coloca eso ahí, no sé por qué.

Answer (score 2):

aplica los estilos directamente al `th` de cada elemento padre

```
.tabla-cuaresma thead tr th {
    background-color: rgba(130, 50, 162, 0.72);
}

#titulo-cuaresma th {
    background-color: rgba(130, 50, 162, 0.72);
}
```

Comment: Gracias, lo resolví aplicando a `th` directamente tal como tú y @Shaz han indicado.

Answer (score 2):

Esto es lo que realmente tienes en tu web:

```css
.tabla-cuaresma {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tabla-cuaresma td,
th {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.tabla-cuaresma thead {
  background-color: rgba(130, 50, 162, 0.72);
}

#titulo-cuaresma {
  background-color: rgba(121, 60, 144, 0.6);
}

th { /* Este estilo tiene más importancia porque se
    aplica directamente a la etiqueta */
    background: #333;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="tabla-cuaresma">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">SEMANA-DÍA</th>

        <th>HOMILÍAS</th>

        <th>LECTURAS</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tr>
      <td></td>

      <td>Miércoles</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-00_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-04-miercoles-ceniza" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Jl</strong> 2, 12-18: <em>Rasgad vuestros corazones, no vuestros vestidos</em><br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 50, 3-4. 5-6ab. 12-13. 14 y 17: <em>Misericordia, Señor, hemos pecado</em><br>
        <strong>2 Cor</strong> 5, 20—6, 2: <em>Reconciliaos con Dios: ahora es tiempo favorable</em><br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Mt-06_01-06-y-16-18" target="_blank"><strong>Mt</strong> 6, 1-6. 16-18</a>: <em>Tu Padre, que ve en lo secreto, te recompensará</em><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>

      <td>Jueves</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-00_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-05-jueves-despues-de-ceniza" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Dt</strong> 30, 15-20: <em>Mira: yo os propongo hoy bendición y maldición</em><br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 1, 1-2. 3. 4 y 6: <em>Dichoso el hombre que ha puesto su confianza en el Señor</em><br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Lc-09_22-25" target="_blank"><strong>Lc</strong> 9, 22-25</a>: <em>El que pierda su vida por mi causa la salvará</em><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>

      <td>Viernes</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-00_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-06-viernes-despues-de-ceniza" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Is</strong> 58, 1-9a: <em>Este es el ayuno que yo quiero</em><br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 50, 3-4. 5-6ab. 18-19: <em>Un corazón quebrantado y humillado, oh Dios, tú no lo desprecias</em><br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Mt-09_14-15" target="_blank"><strong>Mt</strong> 9, 14-15</a>: <em>Cuando les sea arrebatado el esposo, entonces ayunarán</em><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>

      <td>Sábado</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-00_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-07-sabado-despues-de-ceniza" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Is</strong> 58, 9b-14: <em>Cuando ofrezcas al hambriento de lo tuyo, brillará tu luz en las tinieblas</em><br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 85, 1b-2. 3-4. 5-6: <em>Enséñame, Señor, tu camino, para que siga tu verdad</em><br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Lc-05_27-32" target="_blank"><strong>Lc</strong> 5, 27-32</a>: <em>No he venido a llamar a los justos, sino a los pecadores a que se conviertan</em><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="titulo-cuaresma">
      <th colspan="4"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="false">SEMANA I (DOMINGOS)</i></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>I</td>

      <td>Domingo (A)</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias-ciclo-a_semana-01_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-01-domingo" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Gn</strong> 2, 7-9; 3, 1-7<br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 50, 3-4. 5-6ab. 12-13. 14 y 17<br>
        <strong>Rm</strong> 5, 12-19<br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Mt-04_01-11" target="_blank"><strong>Mt</strong> 4, 1-11</a><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>I</td>

      <td>Domingo (B)</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias-ciclo-b_semana-01_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-01-domingo" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Gn</strong> 9, 8-15<br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 24, 4-5a. 6-7cd. 8-9<br>
        <strong>1 Pe</strong> 3, 18-22<br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Mc-01_12-15" target="_blank"><strong>Mc</strong> 1, 12-15</a><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>I</td>

      <td>Domingo (C)</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias-ciclo-c_semana-01_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-01-domingo" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Dt</strong> 26, 4-10: <em>Profesión de fe del pueblo escogido</em><br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 90, 1-2. 10-15: <em>Está conmigo, Señor, en la tribulación</em><br>
        <strong>Rm</strong> 10, 8-13: <em>Profesión de fe del que cree en Jesucristo</em><br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Lc-04_01-13" target="_blank"><strong>Lc</strong> 4, 1-13</a>: <em>El Espíritu lo fue llevando por el desierto, mientras era tentado</em><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="subtitulo-cuaresma">
      <th colspan="4">Ferias Semana I</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>I</td>

      <td>Lunes</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-01_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-02-lunes" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Lv</strong> 19, 1-2. 11-18: <em>Juzga con justicia a tu prójimo</em><br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 18, 8. 9. 10. 15: <em>Tus palabras, Señor, son espíritu y vida</em><br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Mt-25_31-46" target="_blank"><strong>Mt</strong> 25, 31-46</a>: <em>Cada vez que lo hicisteis con uno de estos, mis hermanos más pequeños, conmigo lo hicisteis</em><br></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Una solución:

```css
.tabla-cuaresma {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tabla-cuaresma td,
th {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

/* indicamos que se ha de aplicar a los th */
.tabla-cuaresma thead th { 
  background-color: rgba(130, 50, 162, 0.72);
}

#titulo-cuaresma th {
  background-color: rgba(121, 60, 144, 0.6);
}

th { 
    background: #333;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="tabla-cuaresma">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">SEMANA-DÍA</th>

        <th>HOMILÍAS</th>

        <th>LECTURAS</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tr>
      <td></td>

      <td>Miércoles</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-00_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-04-miercoles-ceniza" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Jl</strong> 2, 12-18: <em>Rasgad vuestros corazones, no vuestros vestidos</em><br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 50, 3-4. 5-6ab. 12-13. 14 y 17: <em>Misericordia, Señor, hemos pecado</em><br>
        <strong>2 Cor</strong> 5, 20—6, 2: <em>Reconciliaos con Dios: ahora es tiempo favorable</em><br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Mt-06_01-06-y-16-18" target="_blank"><strong>Mt</strong> 6, 1-6. 16-18</a>: <em>Tu Padre, que ve en lo secreto, te recompensará</em><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>

      <td>Jueves</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-00_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-05-jueves-despues-de-ceniza" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Dt</strong> 30, 15-20: <em>Mira: yo os propongo hoy bendición y maldición</em><br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 1, 1-2. 3. 4 y 6: <em>Dichoso el hombre que ha puesto su confianza en el Señor</em><br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Lc-09_22-25" target="_blank"><strong>Lc</strong> 9, 22-25</a>: <em>El que pierda su vida por mi causa la salvará</em><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>

      <td>Viernes</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-00_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-06-viernes-despues-de-ceniza" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Is</strong> 58, 1-9a: <em>Este es el ayuno que yo quiero</em><br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 50, 3-4. 5-6ab. 18-19: <em>Un corazón quebrantado y humillado, oh Dios, tú no lo desprecias</em><br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Mt-09_14-15" target="_blank"><strong>Mt</strong> 9, 14-15</a>: <em>Cuando les sea arrebatado el esposo, entonces ayunarán</em><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>

      <td>Sábado</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-00_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-07-sabado-despues-de-ceniza" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Is</strong> 58, 9b-14: <em>Cuando ofrezcas al hambriento de lo tuyo, brillará tu luz en las tinieblas</em><br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 85, 1b-2. 3-4. 5-6: <em>Enséñame, Señor, tu camino, para que siga tu verdad</em><br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Lc-05_27-32" target="_blank"><strong>Lc</strong> 5, 27-32</a>: <em>No he venido a llamar a los justos, sino a los pecadores a que se conviertan</em><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="titulo-cuaresma">
      <th colspan="4"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="false">SEMANA I (DOMINGOS)</i></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>I</td>

      <td>Domingo (A)</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias-ciclo-a_semana-01_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-01-domingo" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Gn</strong> 2, 7-9; 3, 1-7<br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 50, 3-4. 5-6ab. 12-13. 14 y 17<br>
        <strong>Rm</strong> 5, 12-19<br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Mt-04_01-11" target="_blank"><strong>Mt</strong> 4, 1-11</a><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>I</td>

      <td>Domingo (B)</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias-ciclo-b_semana-01_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-01-domingo" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Gn</strong> 9, 8-15<br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 24, 4-5a. 6-7cd. 8-9<br>
        <strong>1 Pe</strong> 3, 18-22<br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Mc-01_12-15" target="_blank"><strong>Mc</strong> 1, 12-15</a><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>I</td>

      <td>Domingo (C)</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias-ciclo-c_semana-01_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-01-domingo" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Dt</strong> 26, 4-10: <em>Profesión de fe del pueblo escogido</em><br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 90, 1-2. 10-15: <em>Está conmigo, Señor, en la tribulación</em><br>
        <strong>Rm</strong> 10, 8-13: <em>Profesión de fe del que cree en Jesucristo</em><br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Lc-04_01-13" target="_blank"><strong>Lc</strong> 4, 1-13</a>: <em>El Espíritu lo fue llevando por el desierto, mientras era tentado</em><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="subtitulo-cuaresma">
      <th colspan="4">Ferias Semana I</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>I</td>

      <td>Lunes</td>

      <td><a href="http://deiverbum.org/homilias_semana-01_tiempo-cuaresma_dia-02-lunes" target="_blank&quot;">Homilías</a></td>

      <td><strong>Lv</strong> 19, 1-2. 11-18: <em>Juzga con justicia a tu prójimo</em><br>
        <strong>Sal</strong> 18, 8. 9. 10. 15: <em>Tus palabras, Señor, son espíritu y vida</em><br>
        <a href="http://deiverbum.org/Mt-25_31-46" target="_blank"><strong>Mt</strong> 25, 31-46</a>: <em>Cada vez que lo hicisteis con uno de estos, mis hermanos más pequeños, conmigo lo hicisteis</em><br></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque tiene en el children un background negro, entonces deberías aplicar ese estilo de color al `th` que está dentro del `tbody`.

```
.tabla-cuaresma tbody tr th {
    background-color: rgba(130, 50, 162, 0.72);
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué aporta esto de distinto a las demás respuestas?

Comment: Es una solución, creo que tardé en "agregar la respuesta" porque cuando empecé a escribir no habían respuestas.

Comment: Ténlo en cuenta para la próxima ocasión, te expones a votos negativos, la primer respuesta fue publicada 10 minutos antes de la tuya.